# Observer Design Pattern vs "Listeners"

Tags: design-patterns, language-agnostic, listener, observer-pattern

It seems to me that the Observer design pattern as described in GoF is really the same thing as Listeners found in various toolkits. Is there a difference between the concepts, or are Listeners and Observers really the same thing.

(I'm not looking for any specific computer language implementation, I just want to understand the difference (if any) from a design point of view. Yes, I know there are several answers to similar questions on SO, but they're rooted in specific questions about specific languages -- I'm looking for a design answer, not a language answer.)

Comment: In the former one code watches the other code for movement, while in latter one code listens to the other code for any noise.

Comment: What does GOF stand for?

Comment: @dekaru Gang of Four: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns

Comment: lol, I was going to ask what's SOF

Comment: @bigstones -- good point, fixed!

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Whether the term "listener" refers to the Observer pattern or not will depend upon the context.  For example, Java Swing's "Event Listeners" are part of an Observer pattern implementation while .Net "Trace Listeners" are not.

It isn't uncommon for framework authors to assign different names to components participating in a given pattern implementation, but the official pattern names are generally used when discussing the patterns themselves.

Concerning design, the implementation of a given pattern will often be influenced by the language and platform being used.  As such, a particular implementation of the Observer pattern within a given framework (which may happen to use the term "listener" to describe the role of the ConcreteObserver) might differ slightly from that described in the Design Patterns book.

Comment: You mentioned that .NET  "Trace Listeners" are not part of an Observer pattern. What are they?

Comment: I'm not sure if you're asking what their purpose is or to which pattern they belong.  .Net trace listeners are just pluggable sinks for writing a stream of log messages (e.g. write to console, write to file, write to event log, etc.)  In terms of patterns, while the overall .Net trace functionality employs several patterns (Plugin, Iterator), looping over a collection of objects which all conform to the same interface is really just plain-jane polymorphism.  TraceListeners themselves aren't concerned with changes of state in an observed object though, so this isn't quite the observer pattern.

Answer (score 34):

There's a two-way nature to the description of Observer in Design Patterns by Gamma et. al. (GoF).

In their description of Observer, one of the ConcreteObservers might signal a change to its Subject.   The Subject, which holds a list of all ConcreteObservers, then notifies its list.   All ConcreteObservers, including the prime mover, then react as appropriate.

The common implementations of Listeners seem to all react to events from outside.

So, I would say that the Listener is a less-generalized case of an Observer.

### Naming example

If you just wonder what name to use, you probably want to use "listener" for simple stuff, and "observer" for anything complex that goes beyond callbacks.

I mean literally, a person can "observe" with many ways, but a person can only "listen" to the external noices which something makes (like callbacks, notifications and etc.)

Comment: In the GoF Observer pattern the subject notifies observers about a change of its own state. So "State Observer" is actually a more descriptive name for the pattern. It also allows observers, as you described, to act upon the subject. So although Listeners seem less general in that sense, I think they are also more general in the sense that they react to any kind of event, not only a subject state change that they are interested on.

Answer (score 3):

A listener may well be an implementation of the observer pattern. A listener is essentially waiting for an event to occur on a given object, which is what an observer does.

I know you're not after a language specific answer, but it's kind of hard to talk about this stuff in the abstract. So if I were to investigate this in .NET, I'd be inclined to open an assembly containing a listener in .NET Reflector, which will allow me to disassemble the assembly and check its logic against a design pattern.

Comment: _"A listener is essentially waiting for an event to occur on a given object, which is what an observer does"_ not exactly, according to the DP book observers don't wait for any kind of event, but a change in the state of the subject, which then the observer can query for (pull). Perhaps "State Observer" would be a more precise name for the pattern.