# Is an EventListener an Observable?

Tags: design-patterns, observer-pattern, event-listener, observable

I am currently following a class about Design Patterns and was wondering whether an `EventListener` is an `Observable`?

I don't really see a difference between them because both have a list of subscribers and notify these subscribers when something has changed.

Comment: I'd say an event listener is an observer, isn't it?

Comment: [Observer Design Pattern vs “Listeners”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3358622/)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

An `Observable` is simply an object where you can observe it's actions. So anything where you can listen to an action and then be told that action occurs is an `Observable`.

This means an Event Listener is one. Because you can listen to events and the events immediately notify you that they have happened.

Personally when anyone says `Observable` I think events. This is my cookie cutter example of what observables are. A similar example would be a publish-subscribe system which is just events under a different name (it does have subtly different use case).

Answer (score 23):

To my experience, an Event Listener pattern is a different thing from Observer Design Pattern. It is not just a different name or which is part of which.

I have to talk about this concretely. For example, this [page](http://www.willrmiller.com/?p=87) gives a c# implementation of an event listener system. In this system, a listener registers its event handling function with a singleton class `Events` and claims that it can handle a particular type of event. `Events` maintains a dictionary to map each type of event to its handler function. On the other hand, any class that wants to trigger the event needs to do so through the singleton's function  `Events.instance.Raise()`.

**Here we can see 3 differences:**

Firstly the **purpose** of the two patterns are different: Listener Design Pattern is to decouple the event detection/raising code from the event handling code, so that when changing or adding new events handling codes, it does not affect other events handling codes; Observer Design Pattern is to make some objects to follow the changes of another object.

The **data structure** is also different. In Listener Design Pattern, there is only one global dictionary to map each type of event to its handling method. This mapping is 1-to-1. While in Observer Pattern, every observed subject maintains a list of observers. This mapping is 1-to-many: one subject to many observers. There can be multiple instances of such 1-to-many subject-observers relationships.

The **behavior** is different. In Listener Design Pattern, when a event happens, the event raiser notifies a global mediator (the singleton `Events.instance`), because it has no information about the event handlers.  While in Observer Pattern, when any change happens, the observed subject directly notifies all the observers.

Answer (score 4):

I've done some more research myself too by looking into JDK's source code. I think the only difference between them is that an `Observable` uses synchronized when adding `Observers` and an `EventListener` does not (at least `AbstractButton`'s does not).

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, it seems like an event queue where you register listeners for specific events would be an example of an Observer Pattern.