# Swing and observer pattern

Tags: java, swing, design-patterns

I had a task at university of making an application using observer pattern to pass the subject (basics of programming). I wanted to show more knowledge, that it is included in syllabus and it backfired on me. I made an application in Swing + sql, heavily dependable on ActionListeners, which I thought, are a significant example of observer pattern. Unfortunately, my project was rejected because I did not write my own implementation of Observer pattern.

My question is, is that even possible with Swing to replace default action listener? I cannot even check a state of a button outside of it. I am really confused at the moment, even though I know the principles of a pattern and looking for help from your side.

Comment: The usage of an `ActionListener` to begin with is part of the `Observer` pattern implementation. http://stackoverflow.com/a/3359101/2413303

Comment: @EpicPandaForce So what in that case would be considered as a full implementation?

Comment: what were the specifications? Did they say "make a Swing application", or just a Java application? Swing already provides an implementation for the Observer pattern, after all.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Java application freely, no limitations, so I assume Swing was allowed. I just needed the Observer pattern. But then it turns out, it must be an OWN implementation, so I am really lost.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Three common ways to implement the [observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) in Swing are described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3072979/230513). The simplest to emulate would be [`Observer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Observer.html), a single-method interface, and [`Observable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Observable.html), a class that holds (in effect) a `List<Observer>`. Invoking `notifyObservers()` traverses the `List`, calling the `update()` method of each `Observer` in the list.

Comment: Thank you, that definitely helped me with my questions.